# magic.MagicException: no magic files loaded

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, mime

On OSX, I have installed `python-magic` through `pip` on a `virtual env`.

I get a magic file not found error, when I do this,

```
import magic

print magic.Magic(mime=True).from_file("/opt/local/bin/python2.7")
```

And I get this

```
magic.MagicException: no magic files loaded
```

I tried with setting magic_file parameter and I still get it.

```
print magic.Magic(mime=True, 
     magic_file="/opt/local/share/misc/magic").from_file("/opt/local/bin/python2.7")
```

And yes, I have verified the magic file exists.

I use Python installed through macports.

EDIT: I tried the same thing with homebrew. Installed `libmagic` through brew and installed
`python-magic`. And the results are the same.

Comment: Ok. I figured this out. Versions 0.4.3 and above have a bug in them See https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/issues/44. I could not install it from pip(did pip-review --interactive, it shows me there is version 0.4.6 but won't install it). Since the bug was fixed in version 0.4.6 I got the python-magic.egg from pypi and installed it with easy_install, and it works!!!

Comment: Please add an answer here (and if it solved problem accept), Your question is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I posted this a while ago in the comments. Just adding it here to mark the question answered:

Ok. I figured this out. Versions 0.4.3 and above have a bug in them See github.com/ahupp/python-magic/issues/44. I could not install it from pip(did pip-review --interactive, it shows me there is version 0.4.6 but won't install it). Since the bug was fixed in version 0.4.6 I got the python-magic.egg from pypi and installed it with easy_install, and it works!!!